# error with the result of a replication procedure

Tags: r, igraph

I have a problem with the following procedure:

```
library(igraph)
k <- cbind(c(.2,.2),c(.2,0))

sbm_centr <- replicate(
  2000,
  sample_sbm(49, pref.matrix = k, block.sizes = c(24, 25)) %>%
    centr_degree(.)$centralization
)
```

The issue is that the function generates a result with two arguments (in addition to the ID of each replication), so the procedure reports an error: *Error in .$centr_degree(.) : 3 arguments passed to '$' requiring 2"*

I tried, unsuccessfully, to save one of the arguments with the following expression: `centr_degree(.)$centralization[1])`

But the list contains only 0s. Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: sample_sbm is an igraph function that generate sampling of stochastic block model networks. In this case, it is useful to deal with missing data (encapsulating a block that does not mention another block due to the data design).

Comment: Thanks, got it.  I forgot to load the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either block the code with `{}`

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)
library(purrr)
sbm_centr <- replicate(
  2000,
  sample_sbm(49, pref.matrix = k, block.sizes = c(24, 25)) %>%
    {centr_degree(.)$centralization}
)
```

---

or use list element extractions in a pipe with `pluck`

```
sbm_centr <- replicate(2000,
   sample_sbm(49, pref.matrix = k, block.sizes = c(24, 25)) %>% 
      centr_degree(.) %>% 
      pluck("centralization"))
```

-output

```
> str(sbm_centr)
 num [1:2000] 0.158 0.188 0.128 0.153 0.165 ...
```

Comment: it seems to me that the `pluck` function comes from `purrr`, not from `dplyr`.

Comment: @lovalery thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `[[` in the pipe like below

```
sbm_centr <- replicate(
  1,
  sample_sbm(49, pref.matrix = k, block.sizes = c(24, 25)) %>%
    centr_degree(.) %>%
    `[[`("centralization")
)
```

Comment: thank you very much for all the tips, they all work very well